# Runtime Java Generics List in Spring Controller, Services

Tags: java, spring, generics, service, controller

I have the following Spring services, controller.

```
Public interface VehicleService {
 public float getValue();
}

@Service
Public class CarService implements VehicleService{
   public float getValue(){
     .....
   }
}

@Service
Public class TruckService implements VehicleService{
   public float getValue(){
     .....
   }
}

@Controller
public class VehicleController{
  List<VehicleService> vehicles;

  @Autowired
  public VehiclesController(List<VehicleService> vehicles) {
      this.vehicles = vehicles;
  }

  public float calculateCosts(){
    float totalCost = 0.0;
    for(VehicleService vehicleService  : vehicles){
       totalCost += vehicleService.getValue();
    }
  }

}
```

When the calculateCosts method is called, the list of services is automatically populated with all of the classes that implement VehicleService. This will calculate all the costs.

What is the best way to introduce an ENum type to the calculateCosts method so that it will only calculate costs for that type?

```
public enum VehicleType {
    ALL, CARS, TRUCKS;
} 

public float calculateCosts(VehicleType vehicleType ){.....
```

Comment: Modify calculateCosts() method to calculateCosts(VehicleType type) and in method implementation use switch case, this is the simple way you can also use some design pattern (Strategy design pattern) to implement different logic for calculation.

Comment: Would you be willing to compromise on it being a list?

Comment: Sure ChiefTwoPencils, what do you propose?

Comment: You *could* do it by mapping lists to the types based on the enum. `map.put(srvcType, srvcList);`. Then you can easily do either or all by leaving the one you have and adding another that takes the enum which you use to get the list. When you want all call the original.

Comment: Thanks ChiefTwoPencils, but at runtime how can distinguish what object type is in the list object so I can assign it to a map with a key. As the objects are proxies I tried using instanceof but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This is what I ended up doing.

```
 public enum VehicleType {
    ALL, CARS, TRUCKS;
} 



Public interface VehicleService {
 public float getValue();
 public getVehicleType();
}

@Service
Public class CarService implements VehicleService{
   public float getValue(){
     .....
   }

 public getVehicleType(){
  return VehicleType.CARS;
 }
}

@Service
Public class TruckService implements VehicleService{
   public float getValue(){
     .....
   }
    public getVehicleType(){
      return VehicleType.TRUCKS;
     }
}

@Controller
public class VehicleController{
  HashMap<VehicleType, VehicleService> vehicleServices ;

  @Autowired
  public VehiclesController(List<VehicleService> vehicles) {
      vehicleServices = new HashMap<VehicleType, VehicleService>();
        for(VehicleService vehicleService: configServiceList){
            vehicleServices .put(vehicleService.getVehicleType(), vehicleService);
        }
  }
```

}